# Get window pid in Looking Glass extenstion of Gnome Shell

Tags: pid, gnome-shell, gnome-3, looking-glass

[Looking Glass](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/LookingGlass) debugger of Gnome Shell provides *Windows* tab that lists all opened windows. Instance of such windows can be referenced from *Evaluator* tab after clicking, for example: `[object instance proxy GType:MetaWindowX11 ...]`

**How can be process id of process of the selected window obtained in Evaluator tab?**

There is `get_client_pid()` method [defined](https://github.com/GNOME/mutter/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=get_client_pid&type=) in Mutter project, however it can't be called directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just from asking something very similar on the [Gnome Shell IRC](http://irc://irc.gnome.org/#gnome-shell), this is what I found out from the very helpful folks there:

I you open Looking Glass and click the Insert button in the upper right corner (eg. after selecting a window from the Window list), you'll get something like `r(x) = ...` in the evaluator (with x being a sequential number).  You can then call any method on the object like so:

`r(1).get_window_type()`

Hope this helps!

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

In Looking Glass:

- Click on tab "Windows".
- Select the desired window.
- Scroll down, looking for "get_pid()".
- Scroll to tab, click on "Insert" button.
- Click on tab "Evaluator".
- In bottom text field enter last output "r(x)" followed by ".get_pid(), for example "r(0).get_pid()", press Enter/Return.
- Note the output, which is the process ID.